# Rails active record find where nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a cost attribute for my product model and its type is `float` and everything works well.
When creating a new product, a user can enter 0 or leave blank for a free product or enter the cost when its a paid product and so far that also works well

Now i am trying to scope free items, but since float is returning `NIL` for empty fields and i cannot return nil fields.

i tried

`scope :free, where("cost IS NULL or cost < ?", 1 )`

and it doesn't return fields that are blank (NIL) but fields with 0 only but i want to return both blank (NIL) fields and 0 fields. I know float fields in rails 3 return `nil` instead of `null`

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
scope :free, where(:cost => [nil,0] )
```

Answer (score 4):

What I would instead is setting the cost column to 0 in case the cost field was left blank. It will spare you nil handling and make your code more consistent.

To do that just apply a before_create callback on your Product model:

```
before_create :set_cost

def set_cost
  self.cost = 0 if self.cost.blank?
end
```

Then just apply a migration to turn all NULL cost products to 0 cost products.

Comment: +1, only because the OP specifically said blank and zero mean the same thing.

Comment: Yes, using null as an alternative way of saying "free" is incorrect.